# heroku push error no cedar supported app detected

Tags: django, heroku

I am new to heroku and was trying to develop a django site backed by heroku. however when I followed the tutorial and tried to push to remote heroku. it complains

> Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

A quick google seems to indicate I was missing something in Procfile. so what exactly do I need to put there in order to deploy my app on the remote heroku? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[This Heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) should give you everything you need

The example given by Heroku in that article is (in your `Procfile`):

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi
```

Obviously, replacing `hellodjango.wsgi` with your application name.